# Infer return value of nested selectors

Tags: typescript

I want to infer the values of a nested selector. Meaning that the second selector uses the result of the first selector as an argument to select a sub piece of this value.

```
function store<
    T,
    Selector extends (a: T) => unknown,
    ReturnValue extends ReturnType<Selector>,
    NestedSelector extends (a: ReturnValue) => unknown,
    ReturnValueNestedSelector extends ReturnType<NestedSelector>
>(state: T, selector: Selector) {
    const get = () => selector(state) as ReturnValue;
    const getNested = (nestedSelector: NestedSelector) =>
        nestedSelector(selector(state) as ReturnValue) as ReturnValueNestedSelector;

    return {
        get,
        getNested,
    };
}

const initialData = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            id: 1,
        },
    },
};

const myStore = store(initialData, (a) => a.foo.bar);

const a = myStore.get(); // { id: number }
const result = myStore.getNested((state) => {
    return state.id; // number
}); // unknown

The first selector is working okayish (I still need to cast the return value) but the getNested function returns unknown. Is there a way to solve this in TS?
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZynATgUwDwCgCQAKgDQEDKmANptBopgB5SZgAmyiAFAIYBcihAJSIAvAD5E4ANZg4AdzCl8AJUxQQ6MADVulEJnpMW7RKvWbCATwAOOCtVroxSgHKZUmVvZpp0h5mwcPPxmGtq6%20sLikmAy8ooEoZo6ephuHl5UPnSMASZJYFa22OnMmQ6%20YrhinKjczPwkKFmO-N6OwgDeBBAIqIgA5mqiXFES3YiTU5NY5kjILb61UPWYwtwcBSn6ANy40wC%20ez19UINqpZ4jnGDuZe2%20-Jfl2ehjiN34%20LNhiLcZDwwnCGUE4gnWmzUYW2aTunkB6H2UwOuAIP00HwI%20BBSmxFzhrCUR1wKNwvTA-RgYBgsF0ABF6twRp9gHA4PxPvgAEbcdAcrH4GCsfgARlxByJpGJZNOiAAtpYyL4DCIUMrOFSaTB6YziFxuO9uAA6VlwI08t7Hcn9JmqhVKjCYI0gsE7RAAendH0QQv4YBAcq5mD8KOtZywyBAlDOdsVyud%20IynGWq3en3R8xWzCNQrdnr%20AaDiIOgjzXuksgUuCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit:

```js
function store<
    T,
    ReturnValue,
    >(state: T, selector: (a: T) => ReturnValue) {

    const get = () => {
        return selector(state)
    };

    const getNested = <R,>(nestedSelector: (a: ReturnValue) => R) =>
        nestedSelector(get())

    return {
        get,
        getNested,
    };
}

const initialData = {
    foo: {
        bar: {
            id: 1,
        },
    },
};

const myStore = store(initialData, (a) => a.foo.bar);

const a = myStore.get(); // { id: number }
const result = myStore.getNested((state) => state.id); // number
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoaAeN)

You need to add extra generic for callback return type. TS is able to infer it. If you are interested on function arguments inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: Amazing. Will study your article, a lot of wisdom in there :) Really appreciate it!